# FatalErrorException in Libro.php line 12: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Buenas. Actualmente me encuentro en *Laravel* realizando una aplicación para el manejo de una biblioteca y a la hora de ingresar en el modelo un método para subir un archivo me sale este error:

> FatalErrorException in Libro.php line 12: syntax error, unexpected
>   'public' (T_PUBLIC) in Libro.php line 12

Aquí está mi modelo y no veo ningún error de sintaxis:

```
<?php namespace Biblioteca;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Libro extends Model
{
protected $table = "libros";
protected $fillable = ['titulo','path', 'idioma','paginas','tipo','categoria', 'fecha_lanzamiento', 'descripcion','enlace','categoria_id'];
}

public function setPathAttribute($path)
{
    if(! empty($path)){

        $titulo = Carbon::now()->second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->attributes['path'] = $titulo;
        \Storage::disk('local')->put($titulo, \File::get($path));
    }
}
```

Si necesitan ver el controlador y el método de entrada, lo pasaré.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas que las funciones estén dentro de alguna clase. Tu código debería ser:

```
<?php namespace Biblioteca;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Libro extends Model
{
    protected $table = "libros";
    protected $fillable = ['titulo','path','idioma',
                          'paginas','tipo','categoria', 
                          'fecha_lanzamiento', 'descripcion',
                          'enlace','categoria_id'];

    public function setPathAttribute($path)
    {
        if(! empty($path)){

            $titulo = Carbon::now()->second.$path->getClientOriginalName();
            $this->attributes['path'] = $titulo;
            \Storage::disk('local')->put($titulo, \File::get($path));
        }
    }
}
```